How do edits happen without being attributed to any ASE member? Who was the actual author of revision #4 to this question? The Community Bot?
How do edits happen without being attributed to any ASE member?
Who was the actual author of revision #4 (which would be the third actual change after original post) to this question?  Did the Community Bot do it all by itself?
If so, is that really acceptable?  If not acceptable, what can we do to prevent it?
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/31247/revisions

Good question -- I'll ping some smart moderators (smarter than I am on SE systems -- which isn't a high bar) & see what leads to this sort of situation.

It's an anonymous suggested edit (that is, it was suggested by a user who is not logged into an account).
You can see this if you click the "edit approved 4 hours ago" link in the timeline, where it says:

Proposed Jul 14 at 16:48 by an anonymous user

It was reviewed by 3 users, two of whom voted to approve, and one of whom voted to reject it, thus allowing it to be submitted.

Ok thanks Ryan, I didn't know such things were possible.
